# Error while assigning a public propery

Tags: php, properties

```
function CharField($len)
{
    return "VARCHAR($len)";
}


class ArticleModel extends Model
{
    public $name = CharField(100); // Error Here
}
```

When I assign a public property like this with a returned value from a function, it throws the error:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/test/db.php

What can the reason be?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the $name property to contain the string literal "VARCHAR(100)"? Or do you want the $name property to be some string value of up to 100 chars?

Comment: Actually I am trying to write a very superficial implementation of an ORM.
This class can be subclassed and the subclasses will be turned into table with the properties as column name.
Later when accessed with an object, we can update table simply by assigning values to the properties... similar to how Django does it...
Anyway, I guess I have to find another way since this can't be achieved by the way I am heading into...
I wish if you can be of some help...
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the value in your constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can only initialize properties with constants:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php
>
> [Properties] are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

So indeed, initialize them in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks to all... I guess I needa find some other way... :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) you can only assign a constant value when instantiating a class property.